# Has there ever been a "Robin Signal" in the style of the Bat Signal?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, robin

We are familiar with the Bat Signal, a searchlight with a bat template, projecting a bat onto the clouds to summon Batman.

Has Robin (or anyone!) ever been honoured with their own signal? Specifically a signal in a different shape, not just "put up the standard bat signal and hope Robin sees it".

Comment: To strike _mortal fear_ into the hearts of anyone with a phobia of circus acrobats.

Comment: https://condenaststore.com/featured/a-new-signal-paul-noth.html

Comment: Next question, I presume; https://babblingsaboutdccomics4.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/bat_37_001.png

Comment: I don't know, but if there has, I imagine it'd look like [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/S4UNrtB).

Comment: Does Nightwing count? https://64.media.tumblr.com/c14fb330fde5cdcc36946c7fa7df2716/dfb9eaa97e4c5ee1-b1/s1280x1920/e8f3925ae597b55172ab125f1538f9a01a7ef468.png (#92)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, the first time this happens is in the classic serial "*The Vanished Batman*" from 1956. Robin takes over after Batman disappears. Commissioner Gordon makes a change to the Bat-Signal.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Batman: Vol 1 #101**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_101)</sup></sub>

He does so again in "*The Blind Batman*" from 1961.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Batman: Vol 1 #143**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_143)</sup></sub>

---

Damian Knight calls Batman by placing his emblem in front of the Batman spotlight in Detective Comics #1003

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Detective Comics #1003 - 'Medieval'**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_1003)</sup></sub>

---

Poison Ivy and Bane steal the Bat-signal in [*Batman and Robin*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118688/) (1997) and she converts it into a 'Robin-Signal' to lure him into her clutches.

[image]

---

There's also an '[*R-Signal*](https://braveandbold.fandom.com/wiki/R-Signal)' seen in the Batman: The Brave and the Bold cartoon episode [*The Color of Revenge!*](https://braveandbold.fandom.com/wiki/The_Color_of_Revenge!). Note that this shines over the sky of Bludhaven, not Gotham.

[image]

---

And of course, who could forget the Robin Signal from *[The Lego Batman Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4116284/)*?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

### Yes.

In *[Robin Vol. 2 #182](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Robin_Vol_2_182)* (March, 2009), during a period where Batman was absent from Gotham, Commissioner Gordon temporarily replaced the
Bat-Signal with a Robin-Signal, which shone his signature 'R' symbol into the night sky.

[image]

[image]